# JQuery :not:has gives Type Error

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with a jQuery selector.

```
$('#test').keyup(function(){
    var val = $('#test').val();
    $('p').hide();
    $("p:has(b):contains(" + val + ")").show().next().show();
    $("p:not:has(p):contains(" + val + ")").show();    
});
```

`$("p:not:has(p)").show();` select the given types, 
but

```
$("p:not:has(p):contains(" + val + ")").show();
```

gives the type error.

```
$("p").not(":has(p):contains(" + val + ")").show();
```

gives an error too. How can I use `:contains()`?

Edit:
There is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ev1v0cwa/

The `p:not:has(p):contains` gives in Firefox a `TypeError: a is undefined`
and in Fiddle the Error selector undefined??

Comment: You're not using a variable called `a`. Can you make a fiddle for us or code snippet to show a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `$("p:not(:has(b)):contains(" + val + ")").show().prev().show();`

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ev1v0cwa/2/)